# IFS read not working as nixCraft example

Tags: bash, read

I have a text file with tabs as separator:

```
a   1   956 9723
b   2   2   11432
c   3   1307    2964
c   4   2   12586
d   5   1377    11726
e   6   1735    8416
f   7   1320    10443
g   8   1175    9240
h   9   1598    9357
i   10  1405    2066
```

and I followed [the example on nixCraft](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-while-read-function-define-ifs-delimiter/) to extract the first column and last column:

```
while IFS="\t" read -r f1 f2 f3 f4
do
    echo "$f1"
    echo "$f4"
done < file.txt
```

It just returns the whole line. What went wrong?

System: CentOS 7, bash 4.2

Comment: Either use `IFS=$'\t'` or use a literal TAB in IFS.

Comment: @RakeshSharma thanks! I tried `IFS=$"\t"` 'cause I saw some post on SO using dollar sign before the separator, but it didn't work. However, you suggestion worked! Could you please explain more about the single/doube quote here?

Comment: The `$'..'` is a carryover from `ksh` onto `bash'` n some other shells, most notably, `zsh`. What it does is express escape sequences, e.g., `\n` `\t` etc.  With double quotes, it's not special and IFS gets set to two chars backslash n a `t` and since you did not have a `t` in your input you didn't observer it's after effects. Try with IFS=$"\t" and some lines with "t" sprinkled in them....

Comment: But to steer clear of shell anachronisms, use the method I ve detailed in the answer section below as it's completely shell agnostic (csh not included, ofc)

Answer (score 1):

```
TAB=`echo 'x' | tr 'x' '\011'`; # tab
while IFS="$TAB" read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 junk; do
   printf '$f1=<%s>\n' "$f1"
   printf '$f4=<%s>\n' "$f4"
done
```